# Why does VoiceInteractor leak memory?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, voice-interactor

After the activity gained focus, I executed startLocalVoiceInteraction(Bundle.EMPTY). Then finish the current activity by pressing the back button. The "onLocalVoiceInteractionStopped" method got called back.But leakCanary prompted a memory leak. Has anyone else had the same issue?
I hope there will be no memory leak after the activity is destroyed.

```
┬───
│ GC Root: Global variable in native code
│
├─ android.app.VoiceInteractor$2 instance
│ Leaking: UNKNOWN
│ Retaining 7.7 kB in 202 objects
│ Anonymous subclass of com.android.internal.app.
│ IVoiceInteractorCallback$Stub
│ ↓ VoiceInteractor$2.this$0
│ ~~~~~~
├─ android.app.VoiceInteractor instance
│ Leaking: UNKNOWN
│ Retaining 7.1 kB in 201 objects
│ mActivity instance of com.test.media.ui.activity.RemoteViewActivity
│ with mDestroyed = true
│ mContext instance of com.test.media.ui.activity.RemoteViewActivity
│ with mDestroyed = true
│ ↓ VoiceInteractor.mActivity
│ ~~~~~~~~~
╰→ com.test.media.ui.activity.RemoteViewActivity instance
Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.android.car.
media.ui.activity.RemoteViewActivity received Activity#onDestroy()
​ callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​ Retaining 99.6 kB in 1639 objects
​ key = 73f5a0e0-3120-4b30-8871-630974629f74
​ watchDurationMillis = 37297
retainedDurationMillis = 32296
​ mApplication instance of com.test.media.AudioUniverseApplication
​ mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper

METADATA

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 33
Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
LeakCanary version: 2.12
App process name: com.test.media
Class count: 26345
Instance count: 225076
Primitive array count: 141328
Object array count: 33476
Thread count: 44
Heap total bytes: 59606146
Bitmap count: 35
Bitmap total bytes: 31128459
Large bitmap count: 0
Large bitmap total bytes: 0
Db 1: open /data/user/0/com.test.media/no_backup/androidx.work.workdb
Db 2: open /data/user/0/com.test.media/databases/leaks.db
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=121354,misses=229641,hitRate=34%]
RandomAccess[bytes=11694491,reads=229641,travel=74637550168,range=34466142,size=
73324879]
Analysis duration: 3654 ms
```

```kotlin
class VoiceInteractionTestActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_remote_view)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (isLocalVoiceInteractionSupported && !isVoiceInteraction) {
            startLocalVoiceInteraction(Bundle())

            lifecycleScope.launch {
                delay(1000)
                voiceInteractor.submitRequest(commandRequest)
            }
        }
    }

    private val commandRequest = object : VoiceInteractor.CommandRequest("command", Bundle()) {
        override fun onCommandResult(isCompleted: Boolean, result: Bundle?) {
            super.onCommandResult(isCompleted, result)
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.VoiceInteractionTestActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

```
┬───
│ GC Root: Global variable in native code
│
├─ android.app.VoiceInteractor$2 instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 56.8 kB in 964 objects
│    Anonymous subclass of com.android.internal.app.
│    IVoiceInteractorCallback$Stub
│    ↓ VoiceInteractor$2.this$0
│                        ~~~~~~
├─ android.app.VoiceInteractor instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 56.3 kB in 963 objects
│    mActivity instance of com.test.media.ui.activity.
│    VoiceInteractionTestActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    mContext instance of com.test.media.ui.activity.
│    VoiceInteractionTestActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    ↓ VoiceInteractor.mActivity
│                      ~~~~~~~~~
╰→ com.test.media.ui.activity.VoiceInteractionTestActivity instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.android.car.
​     media.ui.activity.VoiceInteractionTestActivity received
​     Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     Retaining 55.0 kB in 950 objects
​     key = 7332a37b-0bec-4d77-a377-45b18e072f06
​     watchDurationMillis = 18182
​     retainedDurationMillis = 13181
​     mApplication instance of com.test.media.AudioUniverseApplication
​     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper

METADATA

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 33
Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
LeakCanary version: 2.12
App process name: com.test.media
Class count: 25489
Instance count: 221110
Primitive array count: 139050
Object array count: 33223
Thread count: 39
Heap total bytes: 58513000
Bitmap count: 28
Bitmap total bytes: 19651696
Large bitmap count: 0
Large bitmap total bytes: 0
Db 1: open /data/user/0/com.test.media/no_backup/androidx.work.workdb
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=120002,misses=226044,hitRate=34%]
RandomAccess[bytes=11679539,reads=226044,travel=69732047202,range=33728319,size=
72013645]
Analysis duration: 3858 ms
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have in place in your activity?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added the code. You can reproduce it by opening the page a few times. @tomerpacific